# Reputation decrease without history

Tags: support, feature-request, reputation

I found the my Reputation decrease some days without any history,

I reported that my reputation [history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364103/reputation-achievements-number-indicator-is-wrong-sometimes) isn't exact, but today I dropped 8 points without any history on the reason

If I'm doing something wrong (which I sometimes do) I would like to know about it.

Reputation is off again, see below instead of +20, its' +12 and not evident in reputation history.

- Notice I started to get rude comments so can/should this be investigate more?
  [image]

**EDIT**

Today I lost 2 reputation points without history

**EDIT** 8/8/18

Today I lost 10 reputation points without history 13,442 -> 13,432

Even  after reputation changed there's no history on why 10 points were down

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/reputation allows you to figure out what is going on. Were you an Documentation user with contributions that gave you rep?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's possible, so reputation from Documentation is been decreasing gradually every few days?

Comment: Well, no that shouldn't happen I think. But I know they recently started removing the code for documentation and I assume that also impacts rep-calc. Maybe something is overlooked when they frozen it causing your rep to fluctuate. Needs a mod or a dev to confirm.

Comment: Other possible thing is that there were some serial votes on your account and that it got cleared. But only moderators / devs can see the whole reputation process.

Comment: @KarelG if that doesn't show-up in their reputation tab then there is a regression as the reversal is  normally a separate reputation-event

Comment: could it be because a user was deleted who gave you an upvote somewhere. the top bar rep changes drop down i notice that when an answer i downvote has been deleted i get +1 but it doesn't show where it came from

Comment: @Memor-X I don't get top bar notification and no change in reputation history. it happened to me a lot in the past. can I see user deletion that effected my reputation somehow?

Comment: It may be an answer of yours that was deleted. You may find them in https://stackoverflow.com/users/current → answers → deleted recent answers. It can also be due to some suggested edit of yours that were approved some time ago and now the post was deleted.

Comment: @fedorqui I don't have (recent) deleted answers/questions with votes > 0

Comment: @user7294900 the problem here is that your answer may be older than 90 days, which is the limit of time for the "deleted recent answers" list. You can check your full list with [`user:7294900 deleted:1 is:a`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A7294900+deleted%3A1+is%3Aa&mixed=0).

Comment: @fedorqui I found in link deleted answer (I didn't delete) with 3 upvotes, after I undelete it there's no change in reputation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079641/how-to-use-xpath-extractor-for-rest-api-response-in-jmeter/45079751#45079751

Comment: @user7294900 you deleted it [on Jan 17](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45079751/timeline#history_2d7bd894-e2a0-4d5b-ad82-c443cee2006b), so it cannot be this. Then I don't know what else can be the reason. Maybe a question with two upvotes?

Comment: @fedorqui ok, I found deleted question in 3/8 I answered with 1 upvote https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45432160/lightweight-scripting-language-for-java-and-scala/45432220#45432220

Comment: @user7294900 it cannot be that one, since it was deleted in 3/8... 2017 :)

Comment: @fedorqui can I change this question( or open a new) a feature request for reputation transparency?

Comment: @user7294900 I wouldn't modify the scope of this question, but rather open a new question.

Comment: @user7294900 To be clear, are you talking about the reputation tab on your user profile page? Or the achievements dropdown from the top bar?

Comment: @TylerH both doesn't show change

Comment: What feature are you requesting here? I see you added that tag but the question seems to be more of a support question or possibly a bug report

Comment: @TylerH I just want to see real history. It can be in both, one, or new page

Comment: @user7294900 have you got any valid answer? I lost 8 points today without any history. Reputation on my acc was 185, now its 177.  According to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation it was never 185, but thats not true.

Comment: @PriyankaW lately I also lost reputation and I needed to open another question and my history updated later that it was because of deleted answer

Comment: @user7294900 thanks for prompt response. I will now check if any of my posts were deleted/removed.